# Show iOS Cordova app files in the Photos app and Files and Folders app

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, image-gallery

I am developing a Cordova app for iOS platform. I want it to be able to share images taken in the iPhone/iPad Photos app or image gallery. Until now I haven't been able to find a solution that does this.

I found that using `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` to store files shows them in iTunes or the Finder but they are still not visible publicly on the device itself.

Comment: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/ This worked for me